# ImageOptim breaks png files

Tags: image-compression, image-optimization

I would like to compress png files on my site. I found [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) program. For jpeg files it works great, but when I compressed png files it displayed incorrectly on the site (part of the picture is cut off).

My question is how to make it work in browsers? I see that ImageOptim uses several tools for png compressing(PNGOUT,OPTIpng etc).Maybe I should set some specific tool?

[image: Broken png image]

Comment: We may be experiencing the same problem, and I'm not sure if this is a bug within ImageOptim or with how Apache is serving these files. Are you also using Apache for local development to serve these files? I've filed a bug: https://github.com/pornel/ImageOptim/issues/100

Comment: @DavidRivers Hi David. It was some time ago - so I can not provide you much details, but I remember that I used Apache on my local computer

Comment: Thanks for corroborating that! Hopefully this helps the maintainer of the software to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [JPEG & PNG Stripper](http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=30).

You can either drag and drop your image files to the GUI or use it as a command line tool.